# Hamcrest check if value is null or empty array

Tags: java, rest-assured, hamcrest

I have a code, which returns JSON, where one field might be null or empty array.

I have this code to check:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf.anyOf;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.blankOrNullString;

// io.restassured.response
getResponse.then()
   .assertThat()
   .body("entity.fields", anyOf(nullValue(), emptyArray()))
```

But output is unclear

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path entity.fields doesn't match.
Expected: (null or an empty array)
  Actual: []
```

What is incorreect in this setup?

Comment: When you say the json has empty array do you mean it is of this format ?

`{
    "entity": {
        "fields": []
    }
}` and as in case of null then this format ? `{
 "entity": {
  "fields": null
 }
}`

Comment: What is the actual value of `getResponse`?

Comment: @WilfredClement, you're correct, it might be `[]` or `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON array are list of values, so instead of emptyArray() use empty()

```
assertThat().body("entity.fields", anyOf(nullValue(),empty()));
```

When

```
{"entity":{"fields":"Wilfred"}}
```

> Expected: (null or an empty collection)
>
> Actual: Wilfred

AssertionError returned

When

```
{"entity":{"fields":null}} or {"entity":{"fields":[]}}
```

Proper validation

I had this issue sometime back, found [this link](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/232#issuecomment-218587199) while searching for details